# grep form bottom and display lines after match

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

How to achieve this task , I have pulled pork updating daily new signatures to the `sid_changes.log` and here is a search keyword "New Rules", I wanted to do bottom search `for sid_changes.log` and split those line after match "New Rules" to new file, I have came accross `grep -A ,-B` but  these flags expect line numbers and I cannot determine line number as it will be dynamic....so these flags are not useful for me.

I have tried so far with `diff` command `diff --changed-group-format="%>" --unchanged-group-format="" data1 data2` and Is there a better technique because I have to set cron jobs to first copy the `sid_changes.log` before it got updated and then diff it with new `sid_changes.log`, so this looks messed up solution ...I am expecting some better solution or design for this.

```
sid_changes.log
-=Begin Changes Logged for Wed Jan  2 19:05:09 2018 GMT=-

New Rules
        Reported CnC Server Port 40669 Group 1 (1:2405179)
        Server Port 45351 Group 1 (1:2405180)

-=Begin Changes Logged for Wed Jan  3 19:05:09 2018 GMT=-

New Rules
        ET CNC Shadowserver Reported CnC Server Port 40669 Group 1 (1:2405179)
        ET CNC Shadowserver Reported CnC Server Port 45351 Group 1 (1:2405180)
        ET CNC Shadowserver Reported CnC Server Port 47221 Group 1 (1:2405181)

-=Begin Changes Logged for Thu Jan  4 19:05:01 2018 GMT=-

New Rules
        BROWSER-OTHER Apple Safari javascript mutlibyte character escaping denial of service attempt (1:45354)
        BROWSER-OTHER Apple Safari javascript mutlibyte character escaping denial of service attempt (1:45355)
        BROWSER-OTHER Multiple browser long unicode string denial of service attempt (1:45302)
        BROWSER-OTHER Multiple browser long unicode string denial of service attempt (1:45303)
        BROWSER-PLUGINS UCanCode ActiveX clsid access attempt (1:45270)



ouputfile.log
-=Begin Changes Logged for Thu Jan  4 19:05:01 2018 GMT=-

New Rules
        BROWSER-OTHER Apple Safari javascript mutlibyte character escaping denial of service attempt (1:45354)
        BROWSER-OTHER Apple Safari javascript mutlibyte character escaping denial of service attempt (1:45355)
        BROWSER-OTHER Multiple browser long unicode string denial of service attempt (1:45302)
        BROWSER-OTHER Multiple browser long unicode string denial of service attempt (1:45303)
        BROWSER-PLUGINS UCanCode ActiveX clsid access attempt (1:45270)
```

Comment: Could you please add one or more examples of the input and expected output? Thanks.

Comment: @David Thanks for keeping interest..... I have edited

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to extract the third change log entry from the beginning of the file?

Comment: Actually new rules are updated at the bottom of the file and I want to split the new rules which are updated, from key "New Rules" ....((Grep from bottom "New Rules" dont know how many lines | split that to new file after match from bottom) > ouputfile.log)

Comment: What exactly do you want the split result to be? A single file with a different log entry separator and, if so, which separator? Multiple files with names derived from the change log entry time? A data structure in some programming language or framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `perl` command like this:

```
perl -ne 'if($_=~/^-=Begin/){@last=@block; @block=(); push(@block,$_);}else{push(@block,$_)}; END{@last=@block; print @last}'
```

Explanation:

- `perl -ne '` -> read input line wise
- `if($_=~/^-=Begin/){@last=@block; @block=();push(@block,$_);}` -> flush last block to array last and start new block if the line begins with -=Begin
- `else{push(@block,$_)};` -> add current line to block
- `END{@last=@block; print @last}'` -> flush last block and print it

To read from `sid_changes.log` and write to `outfile.log`, you can run it like this:

```
perl -ne '...' < sid_changes.log > outfile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to find the line number of the lasts log entry separator and then use `tail` to only print lines from thereon:

```sh
lineno="$(grep -ne '^-=' sid_changes.log | tail -n 1 | cut -d ':' -f 1)"
tail -n "+$lineno" sid_changes.log > outfile.log
```

or as a one-liner

```sh
tail -n "+$(grep -ne '^-=' sid_changes.log | tail -n 1 | cut -d ':' -f 1)" sid_changes.log > outfile.log
```

---

If the input is not a file but a pipe/FIFO and you can only traverse it once you can use small program that tracks the log entries but only returns the last one:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

separator_prefix = '-='
last_entry = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith(separator_prefix):
        last_entry.clear()
    last_entry.append(line)

print(*last_entry, sep='', end='')
```

Usage:

```
python3 last-chang-entry.py < sid_changes.log > outfile.log
```